# How many GC threads should I have?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

My understanding is that with the server GC mode, you get one GC thread per processor for your application. However when looking a dump file, I am looking at different results.

When I open a dump file, its showng 4 procs.
[image]

!eehheap -gc command suggesting the same.

[image]

When I run !threads -special command, its showing 8 GC threads. Why?
[image]

Comment: Presumably hyperthreading.  You have 4 physical cores, but 8 logical cores.

Comment: Execute `Console.WriteLine(Environment.ProcessorCount)` and see what it tells you. It should return the amount of logical cores which is what is used by the Server GC. The heaps on the other hand are only created once per physical core.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This is what I got in dump file from client.

Comment: @Servy Is there anyway of verifying it from dump file?

Comment: @MethodMan not sure how does it related to my question?

Answer (score 4):

You have 4 cores and 4 Heaps (as shown in the dump).

Per core you have a GC thread (for generations 0 and 1) and a Background GC thread for gen2.

8 threads in all. You can see a depiction of 4 threads on a dual-core [on this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx), look for "Server GC: Before and after".

Comment: What is Hepas? BTW this application is using .net-4.0 whereas link you provided seem to be for .net 4.5. Finally I didn't know that Background GC has its own thread. Can you include any references for that?

Comment: The application may be targetting 4.0 but what exactly is installed on the PC?

Comment: 4.0. Even if 4.5 is installed, can application using .NET 4.0 use .NET 4.5 specific things?

Comment: As far as I knew, Server GC creates a thread for each logical processor. As you said though: Server GC also creates a background thread for each logical processor's gen 2. However I was under the impression that there was only one heap for each physical core -- does this mean I was wrong and there's one heap for each logical core?

Comment: @PaulSnow - It can't avoid doing so. 4.5 is an in-place update of 4.0, not an addition.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - this PC has 4 cores, I can't tell if they are physical or logical. And it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So how can we verify if its what you are saying vs Servy's comments of hyperthreading causing this

Comment: @PaulSnow: the Background GC option is on by default. You should always see those unless you explicitly turned it off with the `<gcConcurrent enabled="false" />` setting under `<configuration><runtime>`.

Comment: Do you see any indication (in your dump or on the linked MSDN page) that Hyperthreading could be involved? It was just a blurb, now with 7 Likes.

Comment: @PaulSnow - but it's your PC, how many physical/logical cores does it actually have?

Comment: Its not really my pc. Its a dump file that I got from a client's production machine.